# Unveiling Hidden Nested Subnavigation Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working with a navigation menu that uses a sub-navigation menu that is hidden but shown using jQuery. The problem is that I now need to add an additional sub-navigation menu that is nested within the sub-navigation menu that I have already created.

I have a JSFiddle that recreates my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/Learner12/xkaxbhvj/

Basically, I am trying to get the links (Link D, E, and F) to show underneath "Sub-submenu Nav 1".

The current code that I am using only encompasses the first sub-navigation menu, not the one to be nested within it:

JS:

```
var main = new function () {

$('.trigdrop').click(function() {
    $('.trigdrop a:first-child').removeClass('borderIndent'); 
    $('.submenu').slideUp(); 

    $(this).children('a:first-child').addClass('borderIndent'); 

    $(this).children('.submenu').slideDown(400); 

});
```

I tried following the same guidelines by making a "trigdrop2" and a "submenu2" but unfortunately could not solve the problem. I think it has something to do with with this line of code:

> $('.submenu').slideUp();

That line simply brings everything back up, but I do not know of another method to ensure only one sub-menu is opened at any given time while allowing a "sub-sub-navigation menu" to be opened within that given sub-navigation menu.

Please view the JS fiddle for the accompanying HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `.not()` jQuery function.  This removes specified elements from the current jQuery object.  So the line you were thinking was the problem,

```
$('.submenu').slideUp();
```

could be turned into

```
$('.submenu').not($(this).children('.submenu')).slideUp();
```

to select all `.submenu`s except the one inside the clicked `.trigdrop`.  Then the `.trigdrop2` can be handled just as you were thinking:

```
$('.trigdrop2').click(function() {
    $('.submenu2').not($(this).children('.submenu2')).slideUp();
    $(this).children('.submenu2').slideDown();
});
```

(Note this uses `.not()` again).  And here's your updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xkaxbhvj/1/).